# Expected value of a dice

Tags: probability

$100$ dices are thrown.How many are expected to fall either a $3$ or $6?$

---

Now expectation means, sum of values of dice , divided by number of possible outcome.

So, I have done  like, $(3+6)/100$

But answer given like , it is nothing but the mean value , i.e. $100*(1/6+1/6)$

Which one correct to find expectation?

Comment: Expectation doesn't mean sum of the values of the dice. Expectation just means the mean value of something. They are asking for the mean number of dice that come up either 3 or 6.

Comment: singular is *die*; plural is *dice*

Comment: Say , if the question is "What is expected value of one die?" Then answer will be 1/6*(1+2+3+4+5+6)=21, here we adding values. But why not in previous question?

Comment: @Srestha The expected number of dice rolls that have value six and the expected value of a single dice roll are two very different things. The first our random variable is the number of rolls meeting a criterion, and the die value goes into that criterion. For the second our random variable is the value of the die.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the random variables $$X_1,X_2,...,X_{100}$$
where $X_i=1$ if the roll results in $3$ or $6$ and  $X_i=0$ otherwise. 
Now, note that $$P(X_i=1)=\frac{1}{3}=1-P(X_i=0)$$ and $$\mathbb{E}(X_i)=\frac{1}{3} +0 =\frac{1}{3}$$
So the total number of rolls resulting in either a $3$ or a $6$ is nothing but $$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$$
So, expected no of dice resulting in $3$ or $6$ is: $$\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(X_i) = 100×\frac{1}{3}=\frac{100}{3}$$

Comment: Is it not $\frac{1}{3}$ for $P(X_i = 1)$

Comment: @SatishRamanathan sorry,edited that

Comment: how u got 1/3??

Comment: Say , if the question is "What is expected value of one die?" Then answer will be 1/6*(1+2+3+4+5+6)=21, here we adding values. But why not in previous question?

Comment: @Srestha because previous question asks the **expected no of dice resulting in $3$ or $6$** but in comment above you are finding **expectation of the values obtained in the upper surface of the die**

Comment: @Srestha $3$ or $6$ out of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ has probability of occurrence $2/6=1/3$

Answer (score 2):

Expectation is the mean/average value of something. In this case, they ask for the number of dice (out of 100) that would land on 3 or 6 (on average). Note that the values of the dice don't matter (the value of each side of the die could be 101 to 106 for all we care and the answer would be the same). What matters is that each die has 6 sides and each side is equally likely. On each roll, each die has a 1/6 chance of landing on a 3 and a 1/6 chance of landing on a 6. So if you roll 1 die, it has a 2/6 chance of landing on either a 3 or a 6. If you roll N dice, (2/6)*N would land on either a 3 or 6. So if you roll 100 dice, (2/6)*100 would land on a 3 or a 6. Note that the question asks for the number of dice landing on certain values and not for the average value of the sides that it lands on which would give a different answer and is a somewhat in the direction that your first answer was trying to go (but it still isn't right).

Comment: Say , if the question is "What is expected value of one die?" Then answer will be 1/6*(1+2+3+4+5+6)=21, here we adding values. But why not in previous question?

Comment: 1/6*(1+2+3+4+5+6)=3.5